# Executing a program with an incorrect command

Tags: c

In a program of mine i am calling a function in `main()` like this:
`function(stdin, stdout);`
My `main` function looks like this:

```c
int main() {
    function(stdin, stdout);      
    return 0;
}
```

I would like to ask if there is a way I can add some checks so if someone writes something other than `./program < input > output` an error message will be printed.

Comment: What learning material are you using? What do that say about command line arguments?

Comment: And how is that `function` call related to the question about checking command line arguments?

Comment: Or do you perhaps mean that you *require* the users to use redirection for your program? That is all handled by the shell command-line console. That's nothing you can control or check in your program in a portable way. On a POSIX system (like Linux or macOS) you can use `isatty` to check if standard input or output are connected to a terminal or not. I don't know if Windows have any functionality like that. And as a requirement, it's not very good or user-friendly. What if, for example, the user really want to see the output as it happens? Or if the user wants to pipe input or output or both?

Comment: You can validate *some* details of the command line from inside the program, but not all.  It's not clear exactly which you want to validate or why.  The "why" matters because I suspect that this is an X/Y question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot find out to perfection if user gave inputs as: "./program < input > output"

However, there are some things you can do to get very close:

1.) You can ensure that argument count is less than 2.  (Files redirected to stdin do not increase the argument count)

2.) You can create a special header in your file `input`.  In this example code, we will ensure the file header begins with `#####` (5 pound signs).

Without further ado, here is code that has been compiled and tested:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int ch, count = 0;

    /* 1st check:  A file redirected to stdin should add zero to arg count */
    if(argc > 1)
    {
        printf("Invalid input: argc: %d\n", argc);
        return 0;
    }

    /* The file that we are expecting to be redirected 
    * to stdin must start with 5 pound signs (#####)
    * File Format: ##### Follow-on data....
    */
    do{
        ch = getchar();
        printf("%c ", ch);
        if((ch&0xFF) == '#')
            count++;
        else
            break;
    }while(1);

    if(count != 5)
    {
        printf("Invalid input: file did not begin with ##### header. # Count: %d\n", count);
        return 0;
    }
    else
        printf("Tests passed for valid input.  # Count: %d\n", count);

    return 0;
}
```

Please note that if you start the program with no command line inputs, type `#####` and hit ENTER, the program will report successful/valid input.  And that is one reason I told "You cannot find out to perfection..." ...because you can, with effort, defeat the intent and checks.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the command line arguments that are passed to your programs. Count them, check their value...

Here is some reference : https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/A_Little_C_Primer/C_Command_Line_Arguments

Comment: This answer does not say how to check program arguments. Information answering the question should be in the posted answer. It is okay to link to supplemental information, but it is insufficient by itself.